# How to refresh the 'options' binding in an ko multi select component?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, multi-select

I have a multi select component which I have bounded with an 'options' binding, the 'options' get refreshed based on the value I select in another multi select component.
Below is the first multi select component

```
<select data-bind="multiple: true, required: true, options:repositoriesForSelect, value: selectedRepository"></select>
```

Based on the value selected in this component, am refreshing the options of the second component

```
<select data-bind=" multiple: true,required: true,options: branchesForSelect,value: selectedBranch"></select>
```

using the computed variables to refresh the 2nd options:

```
 branchesForSelect = ko.computed(function(){
   //selectedRepository is an observable array here
  //some logic

 });
```

Which works fine, but in addition to the above, I want to refresh the 'branchesForSelect' based on the values selected in the same component. Meaning, if the 'branchesForSelect' contains values 'A', 'B', 'C', then on select of 'A', I want to refresh 'branchesForSelect' to show only 'C' in the list of options.

Can someone please guide me? please let me know in comments if the question is unclear.

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue? code for the ko.computed function? a codepen or jsfiddle might help

Comment: I want to how can I refresh the 'branchesForSelect'  based on the option I select in the same multi select. I do not know how to do it, I am asking for a solution. I know how to refresh 'branchesForSelect' based on the options selected in the first multi select. is it clear?

Comment: Please provide a wee bit more code, preferably an [mcve] inside the question itself. There's currently too much context to guess at.

Comment: Sure, let me see, if can have a jsfiddle. Will keep you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track by making the second option list a computed. This is what you still need to do: Inside the computed, use `selectedRepository`'s value to return an array of options that are linked to the selection. By using this value, knockout will make sure that after the `value` variable of the first select changes, the second option list is reevaluated.

**After clarification of question in comments:**

Changing the values of the select itself after user input is a bad idea from a UX perspective (if you ask me), but can certainly be done. The code below will show you how. When the first option of a multi-select is active, the others get hidden.

Here's an example:

```js
var repositoryBranches = {
  a: ["All", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  b: ["All", 0, 7, 8],
  c: ["All", 9, 10]
};

var VM = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.repositoryKeys = ["a", "b", "c"];
  this.selectedRepository = ko.observable("a");
  
  this.selectedBranches = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.branchesForSelectedRepository = ko.computed(function() {
    var allBranchesForRepo = repositoryBranches[self.selectedRepository()];
    // We're making an exception if the first one is selected:
    // don't show any other options if the selected one is the first one
    if (self.selectedBranches()[0] === allBranchesForRepo[0]) {
      return ["All"];
    }
  
    return allBranchesForRepo;
  });
 
  // Clear selection when changing repository
  this.selectedRepository.subscribe(function clearSelection() {
    self.selectedBranches([]);
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options:repositoryKeys, value: selectedRepository">  </select>
<select multiple="true" data-bind="options:branchesForSelectedRepository, selectedOptions: selectedBranches"></select>
```

([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zovu3xvx/))

Let me know if you need help finding a nice way to link "branches" to "repositories". Ideally, the "repositories" have their own models that contain an array of "branches". You'd then be able to define your computed array something like `return self.firstSelection().branches;`

Comment: Thanks for this. But currently the above I have it working already. What I mean to say is that, on select of some repositories, the options for corresponding branches are shown correctly. But what I want is, how to refresh the branches options after the selection of some branch. To give an example, if I select 'All Branches' for some repository, the 'options' should not include any other branches in that repo. On clearing of 'All Branches' from the value, then the 'options' should list all the available branches for that repository. Please let me know if its clear? Thanks

Comment: I want to refresh the 'secondOptions' based on the value selected on that multiselect component itself.

Comment: Ah, OK, didn't get that from the question; I'm sorry. I still don't see how a select input would work if you remove options after a selection though. How would you "clear" your selection?

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear. I am using a multiselect, so you can 'remove' each element

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/9o932Lq7/1/ If it is, I'll update my answer to reflect the clarifications.

Comment: Hi, yes something like that. Ok, so I need to have a second computed based on the 'secondSelections' ?

Comment: Hey, sorry for accepting it so late, I was on vacation. Yes, I agree that thats not a good UX to update after input, but its something that I thought should happen in our use case. Like you mentioned, every repo is associated with the branches, but on top of that , am adding 2 other values to the list. 1. "All Branches" with respective to each repositories and 2. "All Branches" for the selection of "All Repositories" . During these selection, its meaningless to select "a specific branch" after you have selected "All Branches" ?

Comment: any comments/suggestions for my above query? Thanks